# How do I prevent UIkit modal from closing during some loading process?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, uikit, svelte, sapper

I'm trying to prevent an UIkit modal to close when some loading is happening.

I tried to pass the options dynamically like so:

```
  <div {id} class="uk-flex-top {className}" uk-modal="{loading ? 'bg-close:false; esc-close:false;' : ''">
```

but when I do that the component reinitialize causing the modal to close and reopen with the new configuration.

I also tried to do this in Javacript but same result as above.

Answer (score 0):

is not clear.
Are you presenting an UIAlertController or similar?
ESC does not close them.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description, I updated the answer.

Comment: you are welcome. Anyway you can memage correctly UIKit View in swift / coca / native. in HTRML seems a bit verid. (I am not a fan of html / css ;: )